# Textarea resizes on focus and leave

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I have a problem that I've never seen before: a plain old regular html textarea that resizes on focus.

Even though I set the height of the desired area, it still resizes to something either smaller or larger with no obvious correlation. I've tried to remove all my classes on the item with no luck.

Is this is bootstrap thing?

and how do i fix it?

link to short video of the problem: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7329y5a96ixajl4/18-34-46.wmv?dl=0

```
<textarea style="min-height: 150px; height: 150px; 
   max-width: 100%;" type="text" name="jobDesc" 
   ng-model="req.jobDesc" placeholder="Write a description for the assignment">
</textarea>
```

Comment: it must be other css on the page causing this, using your code and bootstrap 3.0 by itself doesn't produce same effect

Comment: `heigth` should be `height`

Comment: arh yeah a type, wasnt causing the problem though

Comment: yeah i can reproduce the problem on other projects aswell. So i am guessing it must be css set somewhere on the page. But the inspector shows me nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try using [rows Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_textarea_rows.asp):

```
<textarea rows="4" >
This should force the text area to only show 4 lines, or 5, as you desire. 
</textarea>
```

> Anyway, I think you can check the size of your text area or the
>   calculated properties, clicking on "inspect" on your browser (for
>   example chrome). Then click on  Styles/Computed and you will see the
>   styles you are applying.

An image of the properties:

[image]

**EDIT:**

> I´ve tried to make a fiddle to think about which property is breaking it,
>   try it. It it seems you need to look for a `textarea:focus` or similar
>   inside your css`s :)
>
> Changed snippet to show how also padding property can affect the size

```css
#editor1 {height: 10px;}
#editor1:focus {height: 20px;}

#editor2:focus { padding-bottom: 10px;}
```

```html
<textarea id="editor1" placeholder="Check it!!"></textarea>
<textarea id="editor2" placeholder="Check it!!"></textarea>
```

Improved with comment from OP after solving:

*`I did actually manage to find out what caused the problem. Hidden in one of the js files was some legacy code to manage resizing of textareas. As some of the pages where loading in templates on top of the actual page(in a aside/modal) the code wasnt running correctly. Thank you for taking the time. It led me to my`*

Comment: adding the rows option, did not solve my problem. And yeah i would have thought so aswell that it must have been that focus being sat somewhere. But ive looked through all my css files, and i did not find anything.

Comment: try removing css file by css file, is the first way you can at least have an idea. Maybe it´s inside a complex rule. If removing one of css files it stops changing, check inside anything about textarea

Comment: i'll try that, thats actually not a bad idea

Comment: try adding to your textarea a style with the attribute STYLE="height=20px". This is the one with the biggest priority, and should override everything on your Css`s. Check if it happens again. After that, check the same but with padding or padding-bottom. Check again. Then you´ll ensure which one is the css property inside your CSS´s that is changing the size

Comment: went thru all the css, not being sat anywhere. but i realized that the actual inline height is being changed. on click, so it must be some kind of javascript running.

Comment: i thought also on inline height but forgot to say u and include in the snippet!! huh!!.... it seems there is a js then...

Comment: I did actually manage to find out what caused the problem. Hidden in one of the js files was some legacy code to manage resizing of textareas. As some of the pages where loading in templates on top of the actual page(in a aside/modal) the code wasnt running correctly. Thank you for taking the time. It led me to my problem after all :-)

Comment: Don´t care !! Consider upvoting the comments or things that where useful for you, and maybe they will be useful for others too. Write a solution if you have the time to explain the problem on code and have nice !! :) happy to see u solved!